# Webcam Streaming from C++ to Android Apps

Tags: android, c++, opencv, streaming

I am trying to create a system that could live stream my laptop's webcam to Android apps. Currently, I having a C++ system that processes some object detection algorithm, and what I am trying to achieve is that when a particular object was detected, on the Android apps side user will receive a notification and able to live stream the camera(currently working on webcam) to have a view of the object.

**So, the main concern is that I would like to have some guidances/suggestions on how to stream by webcam's view from a C++ system to Android apps.**

Thank you.

Comment: openCv and javaCv are good options, here is a [**link**](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)

Comment: @HamidReza does  openCV and javaCV support live streaming too? I though I gonna need some server or so on.

Comment: OpenCv and JavaCv are tools for streaming video from stream servers, the can live stream from stream server